# "Class not found" using php/silex

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, autoload, silex

I set up a Silex-project local using a XAMPP on Mac. Everything works fine. Now I uploaded the files to my Amazon ec2 server and tried to run it. I always get the php errormessage:

```
"Fatal error: Class 'Silex\Application' not found in /opt/bitnami/apps/..."
```

I'm using Composer to handle the dependencies. The first lines of my file look like this:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;
```

Anyone has a clue how to solve that? Where could there be a problem?

Thanks a lot! Cheers

Comment: This means a problem with the autoloader, did you try to remove your vendors directory and install them again via composer?

Comment: Are you using some means of deploying via git? Are you committing your vendor directory into version control?

Comment: @Maerlyn: So far I did delete the autoload-file and regenerate it. Not yet the whole directory. I give it a try.

Comment: @igorw: YES, that's exactly what i do. You have an idea? I commit it and check it out with Jenkins, copy it to the htdocs directory.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suspected, you are using some sort of git-based deployment process.

Currently there is no tagged stable release of silex (EDIT: as of now, there is). As a result, composer will install it from source, resulting in the silex github repository being cloned into `vendor/silex/silex`. Since that folder is a git repo itself, those files cannot be added to your main repo. Which means that on your server the `vendor/silex/silex` directory simply will not exist.

If you *really* want to, you can apply the fix of running `composer install` with the `--prefer-dist` flag, which will force to install silex from a zip archive, allowing the directory to be added to your git repo.

But I would say that you should not be committing your vendors into version control. This is also covered by this entry in the composer FAQ:

- [Should I commit the dependencies in my vendor directory?](http://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md)

I suggest adding `vendor` to your `.gitignore` and running `composer install` as part of your CI and deployment process.

Comment: Perfect! I gonna try that, sounds like the solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: @igorw, Doesn't ``--prefer-source`` mean exactly the opposite of what you said? I guess it should be ``--prefer-dist``.

Comment: @dragoon you are absolutely right, I've updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: This was the case with OpenShift as well (as it uses git to let you deploy your application). I was knee deep in shell access before I realized the Silex folder was empty!